# Check if value exists in Firebase?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

screenshot: [image]Assume we have the following data in the Database:

```
"name": {
     "lastName": { "Markis" 
               "PopMal" 
               "Carlos"
       }
 }
```

And our code is:

```
        final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://myproj.firebaseio.com/");

        DatabaseReference users = ref.child("name");
        users.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.child(lastName).exists()) {
                    System.out.println("last name exists");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("does not exist");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

My question is how Do I check if 'Carlos' exists?

Comment: Are you simply looking for `snapshot.getChildren()` from the name reference?

Comment: @cricket_007 what do you mean I don't understand

Comment: `onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {`... Then iterate over `snapshot.getChildren()` to find all the possible last names under the name key

Comment: @cricket_007 I simply want to check if "Carlos" exists! That's all! How can I do that simply? :)

Comment: Are you trying what I suggested, or not?

Comment: @cricket_007 I didn't understand it. Please write a complete answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this code:

```
if (snapshot.child("firstName").getValue().equals("Lovelace")) {
    System.out.println("first name exists");
} else {
    System.out.println("does not exist");
}
```

If you have more values for you firstName, rather than one and assuming you are using a `map`, please use this code:

```
Map<String, String> map = (TreeMap<String, String>) snapshot.child("firstName").getValue();
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue().equals("Lovelace")) {
        System.out.println("first name exists");
    } else {
        System.out.println("does not exist");
    }
}
```

Another solution using `ArrayList`. This is the code:

```
DatabaseReference users = ref.child("name");
users.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {
            String lastname = ds.getValue(String.class);
            arrayList.add(lastname);
        }
        if(arrayList.contains("Lovelace")) {
            System.out.println("first name exists");
        } else {
            System.out.println("does not exist");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I want to check if "Lovelace" exists specifically. Not if firstName is null

Comment: Sorry, i forgot some quotes. Correct is `child("firstName")`. See my updated answer.

Comment: I don't understand you when saying "when firstName has many children".
`firstName` is the second child of your `name` node. Other solution simpler than this it doesn't exist. This is the easierst, a comparison between 2 strings using `equals()` method from String class.

Comment: What I meant is that it doesn't work when lastName has many children, I'm sure there's an easy solution

Comment: i'm not using a map. I keep adding values to lastName

Comment: string @alex mamo

Comment: it creates a tree  .

Comment: It cannot be a string and in the same time a string. Please show me more info. Update you post with a database printscreen.

Comment: Your [printscreen](http://imgur.com/a/zmEZk) is not real because the `name` node is always a `map`. In the case of `Map`, it replaces the old value with the new one. So you cannot have 3 values with the same key.

Comment: You've included each time a photoshopped picture of the JSON tree in your question. Does this tree actual exists? Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in your Firebase Database console. Regarding you edit, the second part of my answer will solve your problem, because it actually search your map for that keyword.

Comment: I dont want to post the real tree for obvious reasons. my app crashed when I use your map method

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for the edit. Gog65, please see cricket_007 edited answer. Correct is `TreeMap` in stead of `Map`.

Comment: I get error on the first line of code: `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.util.TreeMap` and then the app crashed.

Comment: And if you remove the casting or put again `Map`, does it work?

Comment: It works but the code doesn't do exactly what I want. I want the code to sweep through every value then **in the end, as a conclusion** tell me whether 'Carlos' exists or not. Please review your code :) I'll accept your answer when it's operational. For the moment, 1 upvote.

Comment: Ok but now what's happening? If you have a user with his last name `Lovelace` when you run this code, what is the result?

Comment: If I have "Lovelace", I get 1 ""first name exists" output and 6 "does not exist" output" (depends on the number of first names)

Comment: Here: `String lastname = child.getValue(String.class);`

Comment: This is the final line of code: `String lastname = ds.child("lastName").getValue(String.class);`

Comment: We're almost there. As you can see in the picture, there is `lastName`, `lastName2`, `lastName3` etc. So `String lastname = ds.child("lastName").getValue(String.class); ` doesn't work. Do you see the problem?

Comment: We must somehow skip the lastNames and just get their value?

Comment: We cannot skip the `lastNames`. I have added a new for loop. Please take a look. Does it work now?

Comment: `lastName`, `lastName2`, `lastName3` were just examples. It could be anything such as `bla` `hike` and `juice`

Comment: There is no incrementing in my **actual** data structure.

Comment: In my actual data structure, I have keys instead of `lastName` `lastName2` and `lastName3`

Comment: I'm thinking at another solution.

Comment: One more try. I have removed the child and the for loop. Give it a try. Sorry for this to many attempts but i'm just writting code, i cannot test it.

Comment: Finally. It worked! Congratulations to both of us. Answer accepted.

Comment: Happy to hear that. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

For starters, your json doesn't match the image, but here's what I would try

```
    DatabaseReference users = ref.child("name");
    users.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (  DataSnapshot child   : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                String lastname = child.getValue(String.class);
                if (lastname.equals("Carlos")) {} 
            }
```